# Cypher/Neo4j: Convert any to string (due to application of REVERSE)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to reduce a list into a string to adhere to a specific output format which requires a pipe ( '|' ) between the elements. I do it as follows:

`WITH ["three", "two", "one"] AS a RETURN reduce(acc=head(a), s in tail(a) | acc + "|" + s)`

My issue arises by the fact that the array has the wrong order: You see that it "counts" descending while I'd like to have it ascending (in my production environment the array is an intermediate result of a graph query, of course).

So I thought I would just do

`WITH ["three", "two", "one"] AS a RETURN reduce(acc=head(a), s in REVERSE(tail(a)) | acc + "|" + s)`

Unfortunately, `reverse` seems to return a collection of some generic type (`any`) which is not accepted by the string concatenation operator:

```
Type mismatch: expected Float, Integer, String or List<String> but was Any (line 1, column 98 (offset: 97))
"WITH ["three", "two", "one"] AS a RETURN reduce(acc=head(a), s in reverse(tail(a)) | acc + "|" + s)"    
                                                                                                  ^
```

Thus I'd like to convert the 's' to a string via `toString`. This function, however, will only accept integer, float or boolean values and not `any`.

What can I do? I would also accept a solution without the conversion. I just want to be able reduce a reversed collections of strings into a single string.

Thank you!

Comment: What Neo4j version are you using, I just tested locally and it is fine? Also, check APOC text functions https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_text_functions, it would be reduced to `WITH ["three", "two", "one"] AS a RETURN apoc.text.join(a, "|")`

Comment: I'm running Neo4j 3.2.3. I will try to upgrade then, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid using the `REVERSE()` function by simply reversing the order in which you concatenate (i.e., using `s + "|" + acc` instead of `acc + "|" + s`):

```
WITH ["three", "two", "one"] AS a
RETURN REDUCE(acc=HEAD(a), s in TAIL(a) | s + "|" + acc )
```

Comment: Oh my god, so easy that it hurts. Thank you!